# Prototype cells are shaking or shivering when scrolling the table view in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I am new to swift I have an issue  that  is when scrolling cells  in table view cells are shaking  or shivering  when scrolling  the  table view .I follow the below code can any one  tell me the  reason .I tested in IOS simulator not in real  time  device .my question is why it is shaking  in simulator

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("transportCell") as! UITableViewCell

cell.textLabel?.text = transportItems[indexPath.row]

var imageName = UIImage(named: transportItems[indexPath.row])
cell.imageView?.image = imageName

return cell


 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, but I'd do this a little differently. To me, the table view is not responsible for object instantiation, just displaying the objects. So I'd find a way to assemble my objects into an array prior to displaying the Table View. That way when your tableView is loading, it has less work to do.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to suggest as well.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to perform the following changes:
instead of the lines:

```
var imageName = UIImage(named: transportItems[indexPath.row])
cell.imageView?.image = imageName
```

use the lines:

```
let qos = Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.rawValue)
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(qos, 0)) { () -> Void in
    if let imageName = UIImage(named: transportItems[indexPath.row])) {
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.cell.imageView?.image = imageName
       }
    }
}
```